# Conditional parsing of List in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

Consider these three lists:

```
["cal"]          %Execute Condition 1 if list 1 is passed 
["cal",2,1947]   %Execute Condition 2 if List 2 is passed
["Hello","World","Random","List"] %Do not execute anything
```

output expected if List 1 is passed

```
calendar(1, 2016)
```

output expected if List 2 is passed

```
calendar(2, 1947)
```

My Code so far

```
% Execute this predicate for condition 2
cal(X,Y,Z1,Z2) :-
   Z1 is X,
   Z2 is Y.

% Executed this predicate for condition 1
cal(Z1,Z2) :-
   monthyear(Z1,Z2).

monthyear(M,Y) :-
   get_time(Stamp),
   stamp_date_time(Stamp, DateTime, local),
   date_time_value(month, DateTime, M),
   date_time_value(year, DateTime, Y).
```

How do I complete my code to support the required functionality?
What I have tried:

```
parentcal(X,Y) :-
   X = [H1|T1],
   H1 is "cal",
   T1 = [H2|T2],
   T3 = [H3|T3],
   cal(H2, H3, M, Y),
   write("calendar("),
   write(M),
   write(" "),
   write(Y),
   write(")").

parentcal(X,Y) :-
   X = [H1|T1],
   H1 is "cal",
   T1 = [H2|T2],
   H2 is null,
   T3 = [H3|T3],
   H3 is null,
   cal(M, Y),
   write("calendar("),
   write(M),
   write(" "),
   write(Y),
   write(")").
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it doesn't seem like it ought to be much more complex than something like this:

```
do_something( [cal] , R ) :-
  get_time(TS) ,
  stamp_date_time(TS,DT,local) ,
  date_time_value(month,M) ,
  date_time_value(year,Y) ,
  do_something( [cal,M,Y] , R )
  .
do_something( [cal,M,Y] , calendar( M , Y ) ) :-
  int(M) ,
  between(1,12,M) ,
  int(Y) ,
  Y > 0
  .
```